# What's the difference between Entity and ModelEntity in RealityKit?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

I am new to SwiftUI, ARKit And RealityKit so sorry for my very basic question
I have been told to use these methods to load models

```
Entity.load(named: "abc.usdz")
```

and

```
ModelEntity.load(named: "abc.usdz")
```

so what's the difference between a ModelEntity and Entity ?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, `ModelEntity` is a child class of main parent nodes' class called `Entity`.

According to documentation:

> An entity represents ‘something’ in a scene. Offsprings like PerspectiveCamera, SpotLight or ModelEntity inherit from Entity class.

```swift
class Entity : HasHierarchy, HasSynchronization, HasTransform
```

> ModelEntity (like any other entities) is more specific. It represents a model which is rendered and optionally simulated. It inherits from Entity class and conforms to HasModel and HasPhysics protocols.

```swift
class ModelEntity : Entity, HasModel, HasPhysics
```

Often two Entity classes are interchangeable (when setting components). For example you can use `Entity` instead of `SpotLight` class.

```swift
Entity().components[SpotLightComponent] = SpotLightComponent(color: .red, 
                                                         intensity: 2000, 
                                               innerAngleInDegrees: 45, 
                                               outerAngleInDegrees: 90, 
                                                 attenuationRadius: 5.0)
```

vs

```swift
SpotLight().components[SpotLightComponent] = SpotLightComponent(color: .red, 
                                                            intensity: 2000, 
                                                  innerAngleInDegrees: 45, 
                                                  outerAngleInDegrees: 90, 
                                                    attenuationRadius: 5.0)
```

However, the following example can be given as an exception. You need to exactly use `Entity` class when type casting.

```swift
arView.installGestures([.all], for: entity as! Entity & HasCollision)
```